# Quick color panel in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color

I've been working with Adobe Illustrator for over 2 years now and I really love this program. I'd want to know if it's possible to create a window (just like pathfinder, layers etc.) with my favorite color's (or recent colors, and if possible I want to create my own list) so I can quickly change colors to quicken up the workflow.

Is this already possible by default, by installing a plugin or is it not possible at all?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using Illustrator CC(2014) on Windows 7 Pro (and have been using Illustrator for a very long time, indeed)

I believe what you want is the SWATCHES panel. If it's not showing up automatically, find it in **Window > Swatches**

[image: Swatches Panel]

In the lower left corner (arrow is pointing to it) is the Library button. Click that and you'll see the list of standard color books (including Pantone), and at the bottom "User Libraries"

Once you get the swatches arranged on the panel the way you like, you can save them. The menu in the upper right corner of the panel has the commands to manipulate swatch libraries and color groups (the colors next to a file folder icon). You can include gradients and patterns as well.

The save swatches command lets you save as an .ai file or an .ase file (the ase file MIGHT be transferrable into PhotoShop, I'm not sure)

Comment: Thanks! weird I've never seen a save option right there..